# Is there any way to use static typing with declared TypeScript modules?

Tags: module, typescript, definitelytyped

I have this little TypeScript app for node.js that needs to connect to a MongoDB:

```
module Engine
{
    export class EngineCore
    {
        public launch()
        {
            var mongo = require('mongodb');
            var client = mongo.MongoClient;

            client.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', (error, db) => {this.onDBConnect(db)});
        }

        private onDBConnect(db)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know that I'm getting a `Db` class on connect callback, but I can't figure out the way to explicitly type the `db` argument to the `Db` class. I'm using a DefinitelyTyped definition file for `mongodb`, it goes like this:

```
declare module "mongodb" {

    export class MongoClient {
        constructor(serverConfig: any, options: any);

        static connect(uri: string, options: any, callback: (err: Error, db: Db) => void): void;
        static connect(uri: string, callback: (err: Error, db: Db) => void): void;
    }

    export class Db {
        constructor (databaseName: string, serverConfig: Server, dbOptions?: DbCreateOptions);
        [...]
    }
}
```

I've tried importing it like this:

```
module Engine
{
    import MongoDB = require('mongodb');
    [...]
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
error TS2136: Import declarations in an internal module cannot reference an external module.
```

Is there any way to use the `Db` class for explicit typing from outside the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried re-positioning the import like this? the below compiles and runs for me

```
import mongo = require('mongodb');


 module Engine
{
    export class EngineCore
    {
        public launch()
        {
            var client = mongo.MongoClient;

            client.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', (error, db) => {

                    this.onDBConnect(db);
                });
        }

        private onDBConnect(db:mongo.Db)
        {
            console.log("connected");
        }
    }

}

var x = new Engine.EngineCore();
x.launch();
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. Reason: TypeScript is being helpful by telling you the kind of codegen it will need to do for supporting both `amd/commonjs` with the same codebase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works when I do the import from the main file, but I forgot to mention that I use `Engine` as an internal module. I found a bit more information on external/internal modules and it seems that I can't mix them. I edited `mongodb.d.ts` to make it look like an internal module. I don't have namespace conflicts yet and it compiles and runs, so I'll stick to it for a time.